# Cómo importar CSV con acentos y ñ a MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

Estoy importando un documento CSV a MySQL. Lo importo de forma manual. Digamos que se llama "articulos.csv" y tiene dos columnas, ean (id) y nombre. El caso es que al importarlo, hay dos artículos que son PORTÁTIL que por la tilde sólo me pone en el nombre PORT. Sé que el problema es por tema formato del CSV y formato del MySQL, pero no he sido capaz de solucionar esta incompatibilidad. He estado mirando posibles soluciones en Internet, habiendo encontrado como la más normal coger el CSV, pasarlo a txt y guardarlo con codificación UTF-8 y luego importarlo. El caso es que luego intento importar el txt pero me dice que

```
Se encontraron 1 errores durante el análisis. Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "1" at position 0)".
```

He puesto el CSV en formato UTF-8 y la BBDD de MySQL la tengo en formato UTF-8 Spanish. Pero me sigue importando sólo el nombre del artículo hasta la tilde. No sé en qué estoy fallando.

No hay código alguno, ya que estoy importando de forma manual un CSV a MySQL. Le doy a importar, en opciones específicas del formato le pongo columnas separadas por ; y columnas encerradas entre  (le dejo espacio en blanco porque las columnas no están encerradas por nada, y le doy a importar.

Me aparece este error:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC1TIL A...' for column 'nombre' at row 1
```

Se me importa todo menos los nombres que tienen tilde, que me escribe en su campo respectivo el texto hasta que llega la tilde.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo para que me lo importe bien? Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el código que provoca el error *`"Se encontraron 1 errores durante el análisis. Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "1" at position 0)`*. Has abierto ya varias preguntas y deberías saber cómo funciona el sitio, Sergio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me dí cuenta. Ya lo he corregido. Un saludo.

Comment: No veo el código. Supongo que es una consulta SQL ¿? Si no vemos el código no podremos decirte dónde está el error.

Comment: Es que no hay código, es una importación manual. Lo he editado explicándolo mejor.

Comment: Parece que tienes problemas con el archivo en sí, intenta crearlo desde Notepad u otro editor sencillo de archivos de texto, verificando que la codificación del archivo sea utf8. Si con eso no se resuelve el problema, puede que haya contenido con otro tipo de codificación, sobre todo si el contenido viene de otras fuentes. En ese caso lo puedes limpliar con un decodificador. Yo suelo usar [este en línea](https://onlineutf8tools.com/url-decode-utf8) para limpiar contenido problemático. Pegas el contenido allí y recuperas el texto limpiado y lo guardas en el archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Para importar acentos correctamente, yo importo el archivo (en phpmyadmin) en formato iso-8859-1